# Eclipse Maven errors when I'm only using Gradle

Tags: eclipse, maven, gradle, nodeclipse

I began to get errors after downloading Nodeclipse and creating a Gradle project with <kbd>New Gradle Project</kbd> -- sample project "Java Quickstart". Whenever I re-open Eclipse, I get this error:

> "Updating Maven Dependencies" has encountered a problem.  An internal
>   error occurred during: "Updating Maven Dependencies".
>   org/eclipse/m2e/core/internal/project/registry/ProjectRegistryRefreshJob$1

I have never used Maven, but I tried to investigate the error. When I try to open Preferences > Maven, or most (but not all) of its subfolders, I get:

> Unable to create the selected preference page. An error occurred while
>   automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui (545).

I looked on Maven Central and there is no m2e folder in org/eclipse. I also looked in Eclipse/features for pom.xml files and I have folders starting with org.eclipse.m2e, but no org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.

Edit: 
I created a new workspace and got the same error message as soon as I created a New Gradle Project based on Java Quickstart sample project. I did this twice and the second time Eclipse logged an error. Some relevant lines from the stack trace:

```
Exception:org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.MavenPluginActivator.start() of bundle org.eclipse.m2e.core 

Exception:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/m2e/core/internal/project/registry/ProjectRegistryRefreshJob$1

at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.wizards.NewGradleProjectOperation.createProjectContents(NewGradleProjectOperation.java:106)
```

Comment: voting down, SO is not for discussions

Answer (score 1):

First try to build your project from command line.
[Enide 2015 by Nodeclipse](http://www.nodeclipse.org/enide/2015) has built-in Terminal <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+T</kbd>

run `gradle build`

or right-click build.gradle <kbd>Run as -> `gradle build`</kbd>

Then see and think

You are building with Gradle, so don't look at Maven preferences, but Gradle one.

Possibly you confused Gradle and Maven and made wrong preferences, you can try again in new workspace.

Comment: I can build by right-clicking but the terminal gives me `'gradle' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file` (Windows). I was not able to find where Enide put Gradle to add it to my PATH variable. Anyway, I can build fine, this message has always just popped up on start and then gone away.

I have never used Maven, I guess that explains why I have errors trying to look at Maven preferences.

I tried a new workspace and edited the results into my question.

Comment: Ask new question, this one is rubbish, it is still not clear what build system you what to use.

Comment: You're right, the title is misleading. I changed it to "Eclipse Maven errors when I'm only using Gradle", and clarified that it happens on new Gradle projects.

Comment: Voting up, helped me clarify my question